# How to add files in a POST using request-promise of npm?

Tags: javascript, node.js, request-promise

I'm tryng to send a Curl request using "request-promise" of npm. The Curl that I want to send is as follows:

```
`curl \
-H "Content-Type: multipart/form-data" \
-F "original=@./${parent_path}"  \
-F "modified=@./${version_path}" \
-o "${out_path}" \
 ${URI}`
```

My code in node is:

```
BIMFile.findOne({ _id: responseDB.parent_id })
  .then(parent => {
      parent_path = parsePath(parent.path);
      version_path = parsePath(responseDB.path);
      console.log("PARENT!", parent_path, version_path);
      const URI =
        `${protocol}://${host_img_diff}:${port_img_diff}/diff`
      out_path = version_path + '.tmp.jpg';

      request.post({
        url: URI,
        formData: {
          file: fs.createReadStream(parent_path),
          file: fs.createReadStream(version_path)
        }
      }).then((apiResponse) => {
        console.log('apiUPDATEResponse', apiResponse);
      })
```

The result is:

```
Unhandled rejection StatusCodeError: 400 - "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC 
\"-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN\">\n<title>400 Bad 
Request</title>\n<h1>Bad Request</h1>\n<p>The browser (or proxy) sent a re
quest that this server could not understand.</p>\n"
at new StatusCodeError (/backend/node_modules/request-promise- 
core/lib/errors.js:32:15)
at Request.plumbing.callback (/backend/node_modules/request-promise- 
core/lib/plumbing.js:104:33)
at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (/backend/node_modules/request- 
promise-core/lib/plumbing.js:46:31)
at Request.self.callback (/backend/node_modules/request/request.js:185:22)
at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
at Request.<anonymous> (/backend/node_modules/request/request.js:1161:10)
at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> 
(/backend/node_modules/request/request.js:1083:12)
at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
```

The server returns the following message:

```
xxx.xx.x.xx - - [05/Apr/2019 10:00:15] "POST /diff HTTP/1.1" 400 -
```

As you can see the server couldn't understand the post request. Does anyone know how to add files correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Use send files using `formData` as you're doing, but one of the issues you have is that you're setting both files in the same property, and only the last one is set.

```js
console.log({ file: 1, file: 2 });
```

So if `file` can receive multiple files, you need to use an array

```
const formData = {
   file: [
       fs.createReadStream(parent_path),
       fs.createReadStream(version_path)
   ]
}
```

If you need additional meta-data, `request` module provides a [way](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request#multipartform-data-multipart-form-uploads) too:

> Pass optional meta-data with an 'options' object with style:
>   `{value: DATA, options: OPTIONS}`
>   Use case: for some types of
>   streams, you'll need to provide "file"-related information manually.
>   See the `form-data` README for more information about options:
>   https://github.com/form-data/form-data

Comment: Hi, I have modified my code using the array, but I´ve got the same respond. I´m trying with the "form-data" library.